# Share basic Kusto query between multiple queries of a workbook

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, kql

In my daily work I use [Azure Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-overview) along with the [Azure Monitor Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview). In most of these scenarios I am using some sort of parameters that users can use to drill down / limit the scope of the provided queries.

This requires my to provide these filters to my queries, e.g., something like

```
MyCustomLog 
| where TimeGenerated ({TimeFrame:value})
| where Server in ({Server:value})
...
```

The annoying part is that I do not find a way to re-use this boilerplate pattern over multiple queries, i.e., every time I add a filter or change the semantic I have to go over all the queries and update them, which is really tedious and error-prone, especially in bigger workbooks.

What I imaging is what I can do in the plain logging as well – use `let` and reuse it from there. Something like ...

```
let BasicUniverse = MyCustomLog 
| where TimeGenerated ({TimeFrame:value})
| where Server in ({Server:value});
```

... close to the parameter definition and then in each query reuse ...

```
BasicUniverse
| // Do some processing based on that
```

... which would be great as I only need to change the basic universe query once.
Is that possible or is there a smart workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at creating a Log Analytics [workspace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/functions) and pass the relevant parameters to it.

Comment: Thank you @avnera this is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm in my use case.